# How to plot several outcomes for several groups in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a single graph displaying several outcomes (with different point- and lineshapes for each, respectively) for several strata (displayed in different colours) over time. Using this for one group works:

```
data <- data.frame(
  time = rep(c("Baseline", "Follow-Up 1", "Follow-Up 2"), each = 8),
  stratum = rep(c("Intervention", "Control"), 12),
  outcome = rep(c("Sensitivity", "Specificity", "PPV", "NPV"), 3, each = 2),
  value = runif(24)
)

# working
data %>% 
  filter(stratum == "Intervention") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = outcome, colour = stratum)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = outcome))

# not working
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = outcome, colour = stratum)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = outcome))
```

[Graph displaying what I want for one stratum, the other should ideally just be added within the same graph with another colour under "stratum" in the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnO3.png)

If I want the same for both strata it does not and produces following error:

```
Error in `f()`:
! geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The info in last_error() does not help me. Has anyone a solution here?

Comment: Do you need `facet_wrap` i.e. `data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = outcome, colour = stratum)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = outcome)) + facet_wrap(~ stratum)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to display all values in one single graphic, not in separate. I amended the question :)

Answer (score 1):

The `group` aesthetic should uniquely define the points that you want connected with a line. You need to consider both outcome and stratum in that.

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, group = paste(outcome, stratum), colour = stratum)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = outcome)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = outcome))
```

[image]